# RAID 1 or (MSI P35 Neo3) mother board?

Tags: motherboard, raid, sata

What happened was that I have a mirror RAID (RAID-1) and one of the drives died.

As far as I know, one should always use identical drives for mirror RAID (don't mix iszes, don't mix manufacturers, right?), but I can't afford 2 right now, so I bought a new Hitachi 2tB to match my old Hitachi 2tB - the difference being that the old one is SATA 2 and the new one is SATA 3.

The J-micron RAID controller does not see the new drive ... can it be that the MSI P35 Neo3 motherboard does not support SATA 3?

Or is it something else?

Comment: Interface-wise, the SATA-3 should be backward compatible, but I suspect that maybe your RAID controller is being particular due to the firmware. Try taking out the SATA-2 drive and seeing if you can get the controller to recognize only the SATA-3 drive. If so, you know your answer. If not, try it in non-RAID mode, or if you have another system, try the SATA-3 drive there to make sure it was not just DOA. If this works, please post back and I will move it to the answers so you could mark it.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaargh!!!   I atatched it my laptop with one of those universal USB cable sets and the laptop sees it. So, does that look like the J-micron? i.e, the motherboard? Coudl it just be a mtter of jumpering? Nope, the laptop sees it. I need to buy a new motherboard, don't I? sob, sob ... Post your answer - and thanks

Comment: What is the exact model of the drive. There may be a jumper on it.

Comment: Hitachi HI7520. No visibly obvious jumpers & it worked on when attached to the laptop. I remember master/slave jumpers, but an "I am partos a RAID" jumper?? Don't know why I even suggested that.

Comment: I could not find that model, and it is usually a lot longer for most manufacturers. Look at the top of the drive if you have not already...it should be printed there.

Comment: Lots of numbers :-/  hope that it is hds723020bla642  which at least shows up in googole (sorry fot the delay - was sleep time over here)

Comment: That is it. This has all the docs for your drive, so you might want to keep this page: http://www.hitachigst.com/tech/techlib.nsf/products/Deskstar_7K3000 This is the Install guide, which I am looking at now: http://www.hitachigst.com/tech/techlib.nsf/techdocs/828BCAEC817D312A882577F10079F6CF/$file/DS7K3000_DS5K3000_IG.pdf I see nothing about a jumper as on some of these drives have for compatibility. At this point, I would call Hitachi and ask them, and also see if they have a firmware update for one, or both drives.

Comment: +1 again. You might want to post an answer now.  I think what I will do is contact the motehrboard manufacturer and as if it (and its J-micron RAID controller) suppoer SATA 3.

Comment: Hmmm, the motherboard page at http://www.msi.com/product/mb/P35-Neo3.html#?div=Detail  says it has "4 SATAII ports with transfer rate up to 3Gb/s", so it looks liek that is my problem.  Tahnsk for all of your help. Please post and answer and I will award the question to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface-wise, the SATA-3 should be backward compatible, but I suspect that maybe your RAID controller is being particular due to the firmware. Try taking out the SATA-2 drive and seeing if you can get the controller to recognize only the SATA-3 drive. If so, you know your answer. If not, try it in non-RAID mode, or if you have another system, try the SATA-3 drive there to make sure it was not just DOA.

This has all the docs for your drive, so you might want to keep this page: hitachigst.com/tech/techlib.nsf/products/Deskstar_7K3000 This is the Install guide, which I am looking at now: hitachigst.com/tech/techlib.nsf/techdocs/… I see nothing about a jumper as on some of these drives have for compatibility. At this point, I would call Hitachi and ask them, and also see if they have a firmware update for one, or both drives.

Comment: Thanks very much for all of your help. I still suspect that the motherboard or J_micron raid controller on it cannot support SATA 3\  :-(

Comment: @Mawg You may well be right, but at least if you ask about the firmware, you will be able to rule out the only other thing it probably could be.

Comment: +1 KK. I will try manufacturers and also ask at a shop that I trust. Thansk again for all of your help